# Looping through data over multiple pages in Django

Tags: django, database-design

I'm trying to find the best way to go about my problem and I would love your input. I am trying to allow users to scan multiple barcodes into a text area. After they are submitted they are split into an array. The user then inputs how many iterations of *each* value in the array are to be inserted into a MySQL database. I've achieved this using PHP and session variables, looping through the array one step at a time. With Django I've found it a little more difficult and I am wondering if I should just have a "temporary" table in my database that gets refilled with the values from the array of barcodes. The following pages then pull each value from the table instead of using any sort of session variables.

Edit:
I apologize for the confusing question. Let me try and clear it up a bit:
I need to render a view based on each value in the user-submitted array. When it is first submitted, a view is rendered for the first value. When the user hits "Next" a view will be rendered for the second value in the array, and so on.

As for the database issue, each value can have two "types." The user will declare how many of each type is added to the database in each of the views I am trying to render.

Thank you.

Comment: What difficulties are you having with Django? Maybe if you post some code it might be easier to assess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably can port your PHP solution using a [Django session object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/).

I'm not sure if that "one item at a time" is a feature or a "it was easier to code that way" thing, but in the second case - you may want to use [Django Formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/) to display all items at once and avoid looping through the array.

Answer (score 1):

this is nothing about django.

forget that temporary table.

- add a field "*filled*" to ur table
- select 1st not-filled row, and show "refill" page by this row
- then update user input number back to db, set "*filled*" to "true" at same time.

Comment: Or alternatively, have a `user` table, a `barcode` table and a `many-to-many` map between them that stores an additional `count` (this can be zero or even non-existant). In any case, I agree this is possibly a db design issue